# How to implement separate thread for function with return value in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

I have a function camera.acquire() which acquires a new image from a camera and returns it.

```
def acquire(self, exposure_time: float) -> Image:
        """
        :param exposure_time:
            Acquisition exposure time, in seconds.

        :return: The image, as a numpy array.
        """
        #Some other code

        self.camera.StartExposure(exposure_time, True)
        if self.camera.ImageReady:
            with safearray_as_ndarray:
                return Image.fromarray(np.flip(np.transpose(self.camera.ImageArray)))
        else:
            return None
```

The `exposure_time` is a dynamic value that can change at any time based on a slider in the tkinter gui. I have a new thread defined to run this function since it freezes the gui if I call it in the same thread:

```
def camera_acquisition_seperate_thread(self, exposure_time):
        new_thread = ThreadWithReturn(target=self.camera.acquire, args=(exposure_time,), daemon=True)
        new_thread.start()
```

where `ThreadWithReturn` is an override of the `Thread` class which returns a value (the image in this case). I call this function in a gui.update() function which is called every `exposure_time` milliseconds:

```
def update(self) -> None:
    #Some other code
    self.thread = self.camera_acquisition_seperate_thread(exposure_time=(1e-3*self.update_interval))
    image = self.thread.join()
    #Print image to GUI window
    self.after(self.update_interval, self.update) #update_interval is just exposure_time
```

However, this approach runs into several problems since a new thread is created each time `update` is called.

Is there a way to create a thread to run `acquire()` every `exposure_time` milliseconds (this value can change dynamically) and return the image to the gui, and do so again every few milliseconds?

Comment: Try to use .after() function instead of thread. Like so : `your_window.after(500, name_of_funtion)` place this at the end of your function acquire and your function will be called again every 500ms. This prevent your GUI to freeze and you will still be able to aquire your image

Answer (score 1):

I would create a thread pool of size 1 to which you can submit a camera-acquisition task without creating and destroying a new thread with each submission. I would then use a callback function that gets invoked with the return value of a just-completing camera-acquisition task. This callback can then submit a new camera-acquisition task. The camera-acquisition task is passed an argument telling it how long to sleep before it gets the photo. Initially we tell it to sleep for 0.0 seconds so that it gets the first photo immediately. Subsequently, the task is passed `self.update_interval` so that the task will first pause before acquiring the next photo. This removes the need for any special `Thread` subclass or calls to `self.after`. Note that since we are using `time.sleep` to regulate the frequency of acquisions, the `self.update_interval` needs to be either expressed in seconds (the option I have taken) or milliseconds and then a conversion to seconds must be performed for the `time.sleep` call.

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import time

# We only need one thread in the pool:
thread_pool = ThreadPool(1)

# For demo purposes we will return this instead
# of an image:
phony_image = 0

class DemoClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.update_interval = .5 # .5 seconds or 500 milisconds
        self.exposure_time = self.update_interval * .001

    def acquire(self, sleep_time: float) -> int:
        """ We will sleep_time seconds and return incremented
        phony_image.
        """
        global phony_image

        # 0.0 the first time and then self.exposure_time
        if sleep_time != 0.0:
            time.sleep(sleep_time)

        # Simulate taking photo:
        time.sleep(self.exposure_time)
        phony_image += 1
        return phony_image

    def update(self, sleep_time: float) -> None:
        #Some other code
        thread_pool.apply_async(self.acquire, args=(sleep_time,), callback=self.acquire_completion)

    def acquire_completion(self, image: int) -> None:
        """Callback function when self.acquire completes."""
        # Submit new task:
        self.update(self.update_interval)
        print(image)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo_class = DemoClass()
    demo_class.update(0.0)
    # Run for 5 seconds and then end:
    time.sleep(5)
```

Prints:

```None
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```